# Storage disk S3 can not put file when deploy to server

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

I'm having a problem using  `Storage::disk('s3')->put()` to store files to AWS S3 in laravel.

I am writing an api to upload files, everything works fine in the local environment, but when I deploy to the server it doesn't work, and the server returns a 500 error and there is no data in response
This is my code:

```
public static function uploadFile($file = null, $folder = null){
        try {
            $bucket = '';
            if (empty($file->getClientOriginalName()) || empty($file->getSize())) return ResponseHelpers::clientBEErrorResponse('File Empty !', '');
            if ((substr($folder, 0, 1) != '/') && !empty($folder)) $folder = '/' . $folder;
            $ex_file = explode('.', $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $extent = strtolower($ex_file[(count($ex_file) - 1)]);
            unset($ex_file[(count($ex_file) - 1)]);
            if (in_array($extent, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'xlsx', 'docs', 'pdf', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx'])) {
                $uploadDir = $bucket . $folder.'/'. Str::slug($ex_file[0]).'-'.time().'.'.$extent;
                if (in_array($ex_file[0], ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'])){
                    $image = \Image::make(file_get_contents($file));
                    $upload = Storage::disk('s3')->put($uploadDir, $image->encode('jpeg', 50));
                } else{
                    $upload = Storage::disk('s3')->put($uploadDir, file_get_contents($file));
                }
                if ($upload){
                    return ResponseHelpers::showResponse([
                        'preview' => env('AWS_URL').$uploadDir,
                        'path' => $uploadDir
                    ], '');
                }
                return ResponseHelpers::serverErrorResponse();
            } else {
                return ResponseHelpers::clientBEErrorResponse('Please Select File Type JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, XLSX, DOCS Too Upload', '');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return ResponseHelpers::serverErrorResponse($ex->getMessage(), '');
        }
    }
```

I can't even catch the error using try catch.
I tried using this function to upload files when using form with html in blade file view and strangely it still works. Looks like it only crashes when it's an API. I have checked and compared the input data of both ways, they are exactly the same.

Everything stops working when running here: `Storage::disk('s3')->put($uploadDir, file_get_contents($file))`

Response is completely empty and doesn't have any data or anything

Please check for me. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the error logs on your server or you can turn on the flag to display the errors in your php.ini file to see why there is 500 code?

Comment: I did check log file, but nothing here

Comment: Can you add additional line in catch block to write logs to application logs then check it? It's likely to be permission error tho.

Comment: Thank everyone, i did add ```ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')``` and it work !